# Bro - broctl status Peers 0 (?)

Tags: bro

Can someone help me to understand the meaning of Peers (0) under broctl status?

```
root@raspberrypi:~# broctl status
Getting process status ...
Getting peer status ...
Name         Type       Host          Status    Pid    Peers  Started
bro          standalone localhost     running   6695   0      23 Sep     08:55:03
```

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing Peers 0 because you are running in standalone mode.  "Peers" reflects the number of other Bro (or Broccoli) processes which are connected to the process in question.  You only have a single process, thus zero peers.